# How can you view the actual Bitmap on Android Studio 3.2?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I know there is a nice feature which you can view the actual Bitmap from heap dump prior to Android Studio 3, but seems gone. 
[image]

Ref

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40945553/827785

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got an answer from Android Studio team's profiler lead:

> The “view bitmap” feature is still there (for Android 5.0 to 7.1): in
>   heap dump, when you select a Bitmap (or related) class and then an
>   instance, you'll see an extra tab titled “Bitmap Preview” in the
>   instance details panel (next to the “References” tab). That has the
>   bitmap you want.
>
> However, there's a caveat: At some time during the Oreo (Android 8.0)
>   timeframe, there was a change to Android's HPROF serialization to NOT
>   include the bitmap contents. The reason is technical: HPROF is a
>   snapshot of the Java heap, not the native heap, but bitmap contents
>   actually reside within the native heap. In essence, older Android
>   versions were breaking the spec in order to provide a convenience, and
>   this "loop hole" has since been closed.
>
> It’s definitely on our to-do list to investigate ways to foreground
>   that information once again in Oreo and newer Android versions.

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/av3lhx/were_on_the_engineering_team_for_android_studio/ehhlfdt